# MYSQL Foreign Key OnDelete cascade chain of events

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

Let's say there are two tables:

**Companies**

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `allocatedUsers` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `accountValidTill` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `premiumCustomer` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `batteryOptimizationToBeDel` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `tz` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Asia/Kolkata',
  `instanceID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`companyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2378 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the other **rosterTemplate**

```
CREATE TABLE `rosterTemplate` (
  `rosterTemplateID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `end` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
  `isDefault` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rosterTemplateID`),
  KEY `fk_rt_1_idx` (`companyID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rt_1` FOREIGN KEY (`companyID`) REFERENCES `companies` (`companyID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to **restrict deletion** of any rows in **rosterTemplate** where **isDefault==0**

Initially I thought about writing an **onDelete trigger** in **rosterTemplate** that would handle this with a **simple if-else statement**.

Now, if a **row** from **companies** table is **deleted**, my **onDelete** **trigger** would **prevent** the rows in **rosterTemplate** **from deletion**. But in this case I want the rows to be deleted since the company will cease to exist.

1. What is the **chain of events** that take place in a foreign-key onDelete cascade event? 
   Eg: Is the row from companies deleted first and then all the other foreign key rows are deleted later or vice-versa?
2. How should I solve this problem?

EDIT 1: This is the onDelete trigger

```
 BEGIN
   IF OLD.isDefault = 0 THEN 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This record is sacred! You are not allowed to remove it!!';
   END IF;
 END
```

Comment: Everything is mentioned here in the official doc (including the behaviour of triggers etc): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: won't the onDelete trigger kick in and prevent deletion in this case?

Comment: Child rows are deleted first. But that shouldn't matter, and you shouldn't rely on it. Triggers are AFAIK not fired by FK CASCADE actions. So while your idea might work for you, I don't like, because it looks dangerous.

Comment: Basically I don't like the whole idea, because you don't prevent rows from being deleted, but just makes it more complicated. Instead of DELETE, you now would need UPDATE then DELETE.

Comment: updated the question, won't this trigger prevent deletion of rows?